# Android Emulator Not Running - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, emulation

I recently installed VS 2017. Trying to run a blank Android App Project. All necessary tools are installed but when I try to launch the emulator from within Visual Studio, I get this:

[image]

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same problem too.  I am able to run the Hyper-V emulators in VS 2015 but not VS 2017.  When I try to launch them in VS 2017 I receive **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

If the emulator is already running I am able to run the app that I'm working on from VS 2017.  So to work around this I start the emulator from Visual Studio Emulator for Android Windows application and then launch the app that I'm working on from VS 2017.  Not great, but it works.

By the way, the Windows Phone 10 Hyper-V emulators launch without issue from VS 2017.

**Update**

I just installed the latest VS 2017 (on April 8) update and the problem appears to have been corrected.

Comment: Thanks this worked, however, the latest updates don't seemed to have fixed it for me still.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Android SDK didn't install/update properly. You can try reinstalling Android SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the bios file exists try copying it to 'android-sdk-windows\tools' folder on your machine, probably a path issue

Comment: I tried reinstalling windows and Visual Studio all together. Now I try running it with Hyper-V and get a message saying "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" after I hit Ctrl + F5....

Comment: That sounds more like a code error if happening on build, does it give you an exception trace / more detailed error details you can share? Maybe in the debug window?

Comment: That's the best part, I haven't written any code at all. Its a blank application and this Emulator just won't run no matter what I do, I posted this question earlier with VS 2015 more than a year ago and I had the same problem then, nothing solved it. I have Virtualization enabled, Hyper V enabled, Hardware that supports all the things required. Here's the debug window: http://i67.tinypic.com/154bkia.jpg

Comment: It signposts you to a full exception log, look under VS, Help, Logs and probably Xamarin Logs if nothing more obvious jumps out

Comment: Where can I find the logs? I can't see any under Help-> Xamarin

Comment: Ok so I decided to ditch Hyper-V altogether, it has proven itself to be absolute garbage to me so far. The AVD Emulator for android seems to run fine somehow now. I am just wondering where I can find the "Design View" for that in my project? Where I can drag and drop controls etc, thanks!

Comment: Would add that as a new question, you'll get more responses than  buried here, don't know that there is a visual editor with drag and drop for android, there is a xaml editor though

Comment: I'm also getting the "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object' whilst trying to use the emulator on VS2017 but it works fine on the same machine using VS2015.

Comment: In my cases, If I change the VS Language from tools->options, (ex: Japanese to English), the "Object Reference not..." issues are gone. But It occurs again 1-2 days after.  I'm changing the language every day. :P

Answer (score 0):

1. Set bios to allow Virtualization.
2. In VS2017, run AVD first before running/debugging xamarin project.